# Issue with my algorithm for checking if something is adjacent to a point

Tags: c#, algorithm, multidimensional-array

As part of a project I'm working on, I want to divide tiles containing water into 'seas' and 'lakes'. This is done by first finding all water tiles on the edge of the map, and designating them as 'sea' tiles. All water tiles adjacent (no diagonals) to a sea tile are also sea tiles. All other water tiles are 'lake' tiles.

My method for finding the first sea tiles (on the edges of of board) works without flaw. However, my method for finding other sea tiles often leaves out large rectangular areas that should be sea. The code is as follows: (`seed` is a boolean array where `true` is land and `false` is water, `seas` is another boolean array where `true` is a sea tile and `false` is not)

```
for (int x = 0; x < length; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        if (!seed[x, y])
        {
            if (x + 1 < length && seas[x + 1, y])
                seas[x, y] = true;
            else if (x - 1 >= 0 && seas[x - 1, y])
                seas[x, y] = true;
            else if (y + 1 < height && seas[x, y + 1])
                seas[x, y] = true;
            else if (y - 1 >= 0 && seas[x, y - 1])
                seas[x, y] = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot for the life of me find a typo in this code, maybe a fresh set of eyes will help?

The next step of my code is to find all water tiles that are not sea tiles and designate them as lake tiles. This is done with the following snippet: (`seas` and `seed` are same as above, and `lakes` is a boolean array where `true` is a lake tiles and `false` is not)

```
for (int x = 0; x < length; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        if (!seed[x, y] && !seas[x, y])
        {
            lakes[x, y] = true;
        }
    }
}
```

This is another possible source of error, but once again I am at a loss for how it is broken.

Attached is an image that is generated based on the three boolean arrays generated. Green is a land tile, blue is a sea tile, and aqua (or lighter blue) is a lake tile. As you can see, there are large areas of water that are adjacent to sea tiles, that should also be sea tiles, but are instead lake tiles.
[image: A broken map]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Typically, I see this type of check done via a recursive flood fill.  Looking deeper now into your code though.

Comment: The problem is your code checks the tiles in a given order (top to bottom, then left to right) and the tiles yet unknown have sea[x,y]=false. So if you have a tile where the neighbours are all land and unknown, you'll mark this as lake even though it is sea. As mentioned, you have to use a flood fill or BFS algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a messy mathematical solution, You can repeat first block of code N time (where N is equal to your *length* variable perhaps N-1 times because you do a +-1 check at first time). The reason is that you may jump of some tiles which its neighbors are not marked yet but will be marked later. So you have to come back again later and check if its neighbors are marked. Obviously there are more optimum methods which need less process.

```
for (int z=0;z < length; z++){

for (int x = 0; x < length; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        if (!seed[x, y])
        {
            if (x + 1 < length && seas[x + 1, y])
                seas[x, y] = true;
            else if (x - 1 >= 0 && seas[x - 1, y])
                seas[x, y] = true;
            else if (y + 1 < height && seas[x, y + 1])
                seas[x, y] = true;
            else if (y - 1 >= 0 && seas[x, y - 1])
                seas[x, y] = true;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it.  Again, a nice recursive flood fill would probably be more elegant.  Though for your answer, I wonder if just scanning the whole map twice would suffice - or perhaps only if a value actually changed.

Comment: Thank you for introducing flood fill. in my suggested method N-1 time recursion is mandatory because the neighbor effect is being spread one by one. A simple example is a vertical column which starts from bottom and ends before reaching the top of map.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using a method similar to this. I wanted to avoid recursion because I want to be able to create large (1000+ x 1000+) maps without worrying about memory use.